# CRUDL - Accessing ROR item with parameter other than id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-web-api, rails-activerecord

I am designing a Web API and a local database for devices to use. These databases sometimes communicate. Because items in each database have different primary keys, I will need to search one database from the other database using other parameters.

I know to use a `where` in ROR for this, but I need to know how to model my CRUDL request when I'm passing a request externally.

For instance, if I want to delete an item from the Web API with a specific SKU number that matches my local database SKU, I would want to write my request like 
`DELETE http://webapiaddress.com/items/912094810`
where `912094810` is the SKU.

In my item controller, I have tried the following

```
 def destroy
      @item = Item.where(sku: params[:sku]).first
      @item.destroy
 end
```

But then if I call `DELETE http://webapiaddress.com/items/912094810`, I get a 404 error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up custom primary key for your `Items` table.

To do that have in your `routes.rb` something like:

```
resources :items, param: :sku
```

And in your `Item` model:

```
self.primary_key = 'sku'
```

Also you need to specify custom primary key for `Items` table like this:

```
create_table :item, id: false do |t|
  t.primary_key :sku
end
```

OR

```
def change
  add_column :items, :sku, :primary_key
end
```

OR something else according to setup you have for now.

With that you'll be able to CRUD your `items` using `sku` instead of `id`. Also you'll not need `where` to select the record. Plain old `find` method will work fine with your custom primary key, so you'll be able to use:

```
Item.find(params[:sku])
```

Comment: thanks! my `Item` model doesn't seem to recognize `self`, though. any idea why?

Comment: Not really. What error message are you getting? Or any other details you think may help?

Comment: Sorry. I'm very new to RoR. All I know is my `item.rb` model contains this now `class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'sku'
    
end` but "self" is highlighted as red in Cloud9 (my RoR IDE) as if it does not recognize the keyword `self`

Comment: Not sure about Cloud9 and its highlighting, but `self.primary_key` definitely must work and it seems you've added it the correct way. Maybe you could type `self.primary_key = 'id'` instead only to try and run your app for checking out if it would work.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is. That doesn't work either - it's only `self` that isn't recognized.

Comment: Let it go that it isn't recognized by Cloud9. Did you run your app with `self.primary_key = 'id'` added? Did your app fail?

Comment: Sorry @VAD I wasn't able to commit changes at the time but I have now and though cloud9 doesn't recognize "self", `self.primary_key = 'sku'` worked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you!